# Is it possible to modify JVM args using java code at runtime?

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify JVM args from inside the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514487/modify-jvm-args-from-inside-the-jvm)

I found an old question about this [Modify JVM args from inside the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514487/modify-jvm-args-from-inside-the-jvm). It is asked 3.5 years ago. Wondering if it is possible now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, it's still not possible to change JVM arguments at runtime. For most of the settings it most likely never will be possible either.

Answer (score 1):

In general no.

However there are *some* situations where you can change some specific configuration parameters at runtime, see e.g.:

- http://fahdshariff.blogspot.sg/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html

Still, it is probably a bad idea to try to change JVM args at runtime - they are designed for one-off configuration of the runtime environment. If you find yourself wanting to change JVM arguments at runtime, I suspect that there is something wrong with your design in the first instance and you should look at alternative ways to achieve your objective.